# How to change permission message in dialog box for Android (React Native)?

Tags: android, react-native, android-permissions

I have seen many posts for the answer but nothing was specific. I want to add custom title in permission dialog boxes (Camera, location). I am using react-native to build iOS and android app. My permissions are working fine. Its just custom text is required.

Thanks